# Cannot Reach Restore Progress Screen In Titanium Backup PRO

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, restore, titanium-backup

On a Samsung Galaxy S I-9000, I just installed [CyanogenMod 10 Stable](http://get.cm/?device=galaxysmtd) and the latest [Google Apps for CM10](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Latest_Version/Google_Apps). TB Pro is version 5.7.0.1.

I started a restore (missing apps with data) and during the restore I accidentally hit the home button. The restore is in progress, as evidenced by the status bar at 37%, but it is stuck at 37%. It might need a TB password or some other information to complete the restore of some app. My problem is that I CANNOT access the restore progress screen via TB or via the status bar. If I try to reinitiate the restore it tells me there is an operation already in progress.

**How do I get back to the restore progress screen so I can give it the input it needs to complete the restore operation?**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Cyanogemod 7.2.0 HTC Wildfire.
In the end I simply stopped the TB service through the android application manager and ran the batch operation again. It will continue restoring all the apps that have not yet been restored.

This is a workaround, not a solution since you should logically be able to hit the home button and continue the batch process by simply accessing the notification.